# Dendrogram missing when saving heatmap to pdf using draw() in ComplexHeatmap package in R

Tags: r, heatmap, dendrogram, complexheatmap

I created 3 separate components (column dendrogram, annotation, and main heatmap) each using ComplexHeatmap package in R:

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(circlize)

set.seed(123)
m = matrix(rnorm(10*24), nrow = 10)
colnames(m) <- paste0("C", 1:24)
rownames(m) <- paste0("R", 1:10)
foo = c(rep(1, 8), rep(2, 9), rep(3, 7))
value = matrix(runif(24), ncol = 24)
colnames(value) = paste0("V", 1:24)


col_fun = colorRamp2(c(0, 1), c("blue", "green"))
lgd_list = list(
    Legend(title = "level a", col_fun = col_fun)
)

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Draw dendrogram
htDendro <- Heatmap(m, name = "dendro", rect_gp = gpar(type = "none"), 
    column_dend_height = unit(12, "mm"),
    width = unit(150, "mm"), heatmap_height = unit(12.6, "mm"),
    cluster_rows = F, cluster_columns = T, 
    show_row_names = FALSE, show_column_names = FALSE, 
    show_heatmap_legend = F)

# Draw annotation
hta = Heatmap(value, name = "anno",
    width = unit(150, "mm"), height = unit(10, "mm"),
    col = col_fun, 
    cluster_rows = F, cluster_columns = F, 
    column_split = foo, column_gap = unit(0, "mm"), border = T, 
    column_title = NULL, # No title for each split.
    show_row_names = FALSE, show_column_names = FALSE,
    show_heatmap_legend = FALSE)

# Draw main heatmap
htM = Heatmap(m, name = "main", width = unit(150, "mm"), height = unit(150, "mm"),
    column_split = c(rep(1, 8), rep(2, 9), rep(3, 7)), column_gap = unit(0, "mm"), border = T, 
    cluster_rows = F, cluster_columns = F, column_title = NULL,
    show_column_dend = F, show_row_names = FALSE, show_column_names = FALSE,
    use_raster = TRUE,
    raster_by_magick = TRUE, raster_magick_filter = "Lanczos")
```

I then concatenated the three components vertically and saved the plot as pdf file either directly or using draw() function:

```
htall2 <- htDendro %v% hta %v% htM

# Method 1: Direct save
pdf("aa.pdf")
htall2
dev.off()

# Method 2: Use draw() first
pdf("bb.pdf", width = 180/25.4, height = 300/25.4)
draw(htall2, main_heatmap = "main", show_column_dend = F, column_sub_title_side = "top",
     heatmap_legend_list = lgd_list)
dev.off()
```

However, while method 1 creates all three components, the column dendrogram is missing from PDF from method2:

Figure from method 1 (Dendrogram is present):

[image]

Figure from method 2 (Dendrogram is absent):

[image]

I would like to ask why dendrogram is missing from Method2 and how to display all 3 components. Additionally, border surrounding each slice is missing from Method 1. I also want to retain the borders in the final figure.